# How do i decrease the width of a switch widget inside a drawer in Flutter

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

when i create a switch widget inside a drawer it takes all the width possible to fill the drawer width,
i tried wrapping it with a Container and a sizedBox to decrease the its width but that didn't work.
here is an image that shows the result of my code

[app image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgmv4.png)

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

bool value = false;
bool newValue = true;

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test App'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Tile 1'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 50,
              child: Switch(
                value: value,
                onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    value = newValue;
                  });
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple way to resolve.

```
Row(
   children: <Widget>[
      Switch(
           value: false,
           onChanged: null,
         ),
      Expanded(child: Container(),)
   ],
),
```